# How to pass data from one apex class to another apex class, convert CSV file to records in salesforce

Tags: parsing, salesforce

I have an apex class to store data from 3rd party system to salesforce. I have another apex class to create leads, but I am not getting how to transfer fileContent data from first class to second class with parsing the CSV file. Please help me.

```
public with sharing class awsSF_import {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String getCSV
    {
        String endpoint = 'endpoinyurl';
        // Set up the request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('path', '/');
        req.setTimeout(30000);
        
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        
        if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Get the file content
            String fileContent = res.getBody();
            // Get the file name
            String fileName = 'sample.txt';
            
            // Log the file name and content
            System.debug('File Name: ' + fileName);
            System.debug('File Content: ' + fileContent);
        } else {
            System.debug('Error downloading file. Status code: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        }
        
        return fileContent;
        
    }
   
    
}`

I want to move above fileContent data to another apex class and convert it into records in salesforce lead object.

`public with sharing class convertfiletoLead {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String insertAccounts(List<Map<String, Object>> data) {
        
        List<Lead> Leads = new List<Lead>();
        for (Map<String, Object> row : data) {
            Lead lead = new Lead();
            lead.LastName = String.valueOf(row.get('Lead name'));
            lead.Company = String.valueOf(row.get('Company'));
            lead.Status = String.valueOf(row.get('Lead Status'));
         
            
            leads.add(lead);
        }
        if (!leads.isEmpty()) {
            insert leads;
        }
        String succesmsg='DML Successful';

        System.debug(succesmsg);

        return succesmsg;
    }
}
```